# How can I send form content with different subjects

Tags: jquery

I need help with my contact formular on http://robert-richter.com under the navigation point Kontakt. I want to send this form with different subjects. Dependung on with option is selected in the drop down menu, I want to create an individual subject. The reason why I want to do this is because I want to use a filter in my email account wich saves emails based on the sibject title.

Example:

Contact Form Name: John Alex Option Selected: Anfrage persönlich // german for private request

Subject in Mailbox: Persönliche Anfrage von Alex John 23/08/2013

Filter 'Persönliche Anfrage von' and save it in the folder 'Persönliche Anfragen' (eng: Private Requests)

Im brand new to jQuery. This is what I got so far:

```
<form action="#" method="post" title="Kontaktformular" class="ajax">
<div><label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" title="Name"></div>
<div><label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" title="Email"></div>
<div><label for="auswahl">Präfix</label>
<label class="label">
    <select name="auswahl" class="dropdown">
    <option selected value="Webdesign">Anfrage Webdesign</option>
    <option value="Persoenlich">Anfrage persönlich</option>
    <option value="Andere">Alles andere</option>
    <option value="Spam">Spam</option>
    </select>
    </label></div>
    <div><textarea name="message" title="Nachricht"></textarea></div>
<button value="Send" type="submit" class="button">Absenden</button>
</form>

//php file
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['auswahl'], $_POST['message'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
}

$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
return false;
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/c5C8F/2/

How can I add the selected option instead of the select element?

Comment: Your `that.find...` statement contains a function, who has an argument named `value`. Inside that function, you declare a local variable with the same name. While this is not directly related to your question, I thought I'd point it out because it smells like trouble.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/c5C8F/2/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        method = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value; // need to assign value instead of name
    });
    console.log(data);      
    return false;
});
```

If you want to get all the selected values as param list try

```
console.log(that.serialize())
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great. Do you know what to change in the ajax command thingy to get the select as well? Ive updated the jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/c5C8F/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: if you want to do this way as you implemented then update your code like this:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        var isSelect = that.find("select");
        if(isSelect.length > 0){
            value = isSelect.val();
        }

        data[name] = value;
    });
    console.log(data);
    return false;
});
```

But the thing is that, you are going through each input in form and storing the data in keyValue pair in array. If you just update your code to below like this then you dont have to do it manually because jQuery does for you:

```
 $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    data = that.serialize(); //it will return each input in string concatenation

    //Or,

    data = that.serializeArray(); //it will return each input in object array

    console.log(data);
    return false;
});
```

It's your choice which method best for you.

I hope it helps

Comment: @RobertRichter:: you added $.ajax call in it.. so what do you want to do now?

Comment: I dont know how to do this right, select = $(this).find("select[name='auswahl']"),

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected option you can do this:

```
// Get the select box.
var $select = $(this).find("select[name='auswahl']");
// Get the selected option.
var $selectedOption = $select.find(":selected");
// Get the value of the selected option.
var selectedOptionValue = $selectedOption.val();
```

Comment: When I use var selectedOptionValue = $selectedOption.val(); I get a ReferenceError: selectedOption is not defined http://jsfiddle.net/c5C8F/7/

Comment: @RobertRichter: if you still wanna do this way then i updated your fiddle see here: http://jsfiddle.net/c5C8F/23/